# Troubleshooting user access/permissions to Adobe Analytics API

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to query the Adobe Analytics API, but I'm unsure that we have the right permissions in place.

I've received confirmation thata our account has "Web service access" enabled -- however, Adobe Analytics does not appear as an option when I try to "create a project" on API via Adobe I/O. As a result, I'm blocked from actually trying out the API in that environment.

Are there any other permissions I need to request from the Admin?

Do I need to have some sort of Developer Access in place in addition to "Web service access"? Is it possible to have one without the other?

Any guidance would be a big help -- thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need two things before being able to create an Analytics project and query the API: the **Role of Developer** (or higher), and, at a minimum, **permissions for Report Suites, Metrics, and Dimensions groups**.

If you're able to create a project before getting both of these, the API credentials you get (API key, Client key, etc...) won't work; you'll need to create a new project again.

This [document](https://developer.adobe.com/analytics-apis/docs/2.0/guides/jwt/) has more detail about what's required.